# struts2 web application not found

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I have created a struts 2 application and deploy it in tomcat by creating a war file. There is nothing wrong with the file structure as below is how it display under tomcat after deploy.

```
css
META-INF
User
  pages
    login.jsp
    customer_list.jsp
WEB-INF
    classes
       struts.xml
    lib
    web.xml
```

But it gives the below error when i try to access the web site,

HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/LoginApplication/User/Login) is not available.

But i found when tomcat start it gives below exception. But the jar file that claims to say missing is in right path.

```
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/tomcat6/webapps/LoginApplication/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:54:89
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:449)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
```

Below is the struts.xml file,

```
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 

    <package name="user" namespace="/User" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Login">
            <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Welcome" class="loginapplication.action.UserLoginAction">
            <result type="redirect" name="SUCCESS">Customers</result>
            <result name="input">pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Customers" class="loginapplication.action.ViewCustomerAction">
            <result name="SUCCESS">pages/customer_list.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

Comment: Have you placed Struts jars inside tomcat. Sometimes if the jar's are loaded twice it will throw this error

Comment: i have not placed the jar inside tomcat

Comment: Nothing says anything is missing. Please show the rest of the exception. Without further info I'd guess you're either missing a library, or have the S2 library/libraries on the class path twice.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates you have got problems with struts.xml file. Pls post that here. Also use Maven for managing dependency. You will never have to bother about folders then.

Pls verify the libraries and versions in your lib.

- commons-logging-1.1.jar
- freemarker-2.3.8.jar
- ognl-2.6.11.jar
- struts2-core-2.0.6.jar
- xwork-2.0.1.jar

Comment: @HarshanaD pls verify the libraries and versions. added in my answer

Comment: @HarshanaD go for maven. or best option is to download struts-blank.war and use all the libraries. just a change in version is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace for the requested action Login is User. The URL should be like the below

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/User/Login
```

Configure the XML

```
 <package name="User" namespace="/User" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Login">
            <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Note that package name and namespace  are same

Comment: yes i am accessing the application with namespace. it was a typo in the post where i did not put the namespace